# Make inexact DE exact (multiply by $\mu (x,y)$) and solve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Show that the equation is not exact, but becomes exact when multiplied
by the given integrating factor. Then solve the equation.

$y'=e^{2x}+y−1$ with integrating factor  $\mu(x,y)=1/xy^3$.

I got that $x+[(1+y^2)/y^3]y'=0$... How do you solve from here?

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form
$$y'-y=e^{2x}-1$$
and
$$\mu=e^{\int-1dx}=e^{-x}$$
and then
$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{e^x}-e^{-x}y=\frac{e^{-2x}-1}{e^x}$$
then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y(x)}{e^x}\right)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^x}$$
can you finish?
the solution is given by $$y(x)=c_1 e^x+e^x \left(x+e^{-x}\right)$$

Comment: Would the answer be y=(e^x+e^-x+c)/e^-x?

Comment: The answer should be x^2+2lny-y^-2=C according to the answer key....

Answer (score 0):

Simply integrate the equation, 
$$x+[(1+y^2)/y^3]y'=0$$
$$\int \dfrac {(1+y^2)}{y^3}dy=-\int x dx$$
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{y^3}+\int \dfrac {dy}{y}=-x^2/2+K$$
Another way to integrate the differential equation
$$y'=e^{2x}+y−1$$
Substitute $z=e^{2x}+y−1$ and $z'=y'+2e^{2x}$

You get 
$$z'-z=2e^{2x}$$
$$ze^{-x}= 2\int e^{x}dx$$
$$z=2 e^{2x}+Ke^{x}$$
$$\boxed{y=1+ e^{2x}+Ke^{x}}$$